# Linking libssl and libcrypto in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, linker, openssl, libcrypto

I'm attempting to use OpenSSL's EVP interface to do some encryption.  I'm pretty sure my code is right, but I can't seem to get it to compile.  I'm using GCC, and Ubuntu 32-bit precise with libssl-dev installed and at the latest version.

The project currently consists of one file, `program.c`.

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
...
i = EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha1() ... );
...
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(e_ctx);
```

among other various calls.

Here is how I invoke gcc:

```
gcc -Wall -g -lssl -lcrypto -o program program.c
```

Then I get output like this

```
/home/andy/program/program.c:31: undefined reference to `EVP_sha1'
/home/andy/program/program.c:31: undefined reference to `EVP_aes_256_cbc'
/home/andy/program/program.c:31: undefined reference to `EVP_BytesToKey'
/home/andy/program/program.c:44: undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init'
```

So the include is clearly working:

```
andy@ProgStation2:/usr/include$ find . | grep evp.h
./openssl/evp.h
```

Here is the output of `locate libcrypto`.  My best guess is that this is a stupid location for it and is why my link is failing, so I tried `-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` before `-lcrypto` with no luck as well.

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

I'm kind of stumped.  If anyone wants to make me feel like a fool, I'd be very excited to figure out what i'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It turns out it was something stupid. In the linker step, I was using `gcc -Wall -g -lssl -lcrypto -o program program.o`.  I needed to move the library links to after the object file I was linking, and put `libssl` before `libcrypto`:

```
gcc -Wall -g -o program program.o -lssl -lcrypto
```

Comment: Yep, order and placement matters when linking. The `-l` options should come at the end of the compiler driver (GCC) command. And order of the libraries matters too because `ld` is a single pass linker. So `-lssl -lcrypto` works, but `-lcrypto -lssl` won't work. You'll get linker errors because `ld` already visited `libcrypto` when it visits `libssl` (`libssl` needs stuff from `libcrypto`).

Answer (score -1):

Try including headers using -I option, Look into directory for library using -L and finally specifying the library name with -l

Just making guess here, please specify path based on actual location.

```
gcc -g -Wall  -L/usr/lib -I/usr/include -lssl -lcrypto -o program program.c
```

Hope it may help.

Comment: Adding the include doesn't seem to work (though you had the path correct).  I think the problem is linking to the function definitions rather than the prototypes, since it seems to make it through the compilation part, just not the linking.