# Unsatisfied symbol in file libssl.a on HPUX64

Tags: c, openssl, hp-ux

I'm facing below issue while building my code 64-bit on Hpux machine the same worked fine for 32-bit.

```
aCC   -AA -mt  +DA2.0W ../obj/batch.o ../obj/DataFileReader.o \
  -L../../../../lib -lg1client -lopentop-accmt -lPocoXML -lcrypto -lssl   -o ../bin/batch

[04:09:52][com.g1.cdq:g1clientSDK] [exec] ld: Unsatisfied symbol "COMP_expand_block" \
  in file ../../../../lib/libssl.a[s3_pkt.o]

[04:09:52][com.g1.cdq:g1clientSDK] [exec] ld: Unsatisfied symbol "OPENSSL_DIR_end" \
  in file ../../../../lib/libssl.a[ssl_cert.o]
```

I'm using following to configure OpenSSL:

```
./Configure hpux64-parisc2-cc --openssldir=/san5/hpux/cdqp/hpx5/clientsdklatest/hpunix10.1/64/openssl/install64
```

Please suggest

Comment: Have you tried swapping `-lcrypto` and `-lssl`?

Comment: Also see [Linking libcrypto in GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18835219), [Linking problem of OpenSSL library in existing C project](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5700617), etc...